# How many GPUs my macbook pro has?

Tags: hardware, gpu

I am trying to find how many GPUs has my macbook pro and if I have some of them, what are their characteristics. I though I can find it from `About this mac` -> `System Report` -> `Hardware`, but was not able to find anything.

Comment: The information is on Wikipedia if you lookup your Model Number. You either have a single dedicated (NVIDIA or Radeon) GPU, a single Intel GPU (built-in to your CPU), or both.

Comment: @Dai thank you. Is there any command I can type in my shell to get this info?

Comment: Run `system_profiler | grep "Model Identifier"`.

Comment: Or just `sysctl hw.model`.

Comment: But there is an information about graphics cards in "Hardware" section in "System Report" It's under "Graphics/Displays". There's a list of internal Graphics Cards. (on my 13" I only have one, but on 15" I see there are two Intel&nVidia )